# Aggregate different netcdf variables and write output

Tags: netcdf, nco, cdo-climate

I have a netcdf files with 3 variables, nammed `v1`, `v2`, `v3`.
I would like to aggregate those variables and create a new variable `v4`, as follow:

```
v4 = (v1*0.1)+(v2*0.2)+(v3*0.2)
```

I know how to aggregate 2 variables using cdo :

```
cdo expr,’sum=var1+var2;’ ifile ofile
```

But how could I handle more specific netcdf calculations like the one required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CDO will be able to handle the formula you require:

```
cdo expr,’v4=(v1*0.1)+(v2*0.2)+(v3*0.2)’ ifile ofile
```

If you want to add the variable to the files, just do this:

```
cdo aexpr,’sum=var1+var2;v4=(v1*0.1)+(v2*0.2)+(v3*0.2)’ ifile ofile
```

Comment: I didn't know the "aexpr" command, learn something new every day! :-)

Comment: Just print off the CDO reference card and put it on your wall 

Comment: I'm over 50; the typeface is too small 

Answer (score 1):

you can also use ncap2 as an alternative

```
ncap2 -O -s "v4=(v1*0.1)+(v2*0.2)+(v3*0.2)" ifile.nc ofile.nc
```

Although I would usually use the cdo solution as suggested by Robert Wilson, the nice thing with nco is the ability to define all the metadata too:

```
ncatted -O -a units,v4,c,c,"units goes here" ofile.nc
ncatted -O -a long_name,v4,c,c,"long_name goes here" ofile.nc
```

EDIT: As Charlie correctly points out in his answer to this question, I should have highlighted the fact that ncap2 ports metadata from the source variables, so if metadata such as units already exists you need to either specify the new values in the ncap command as per his answer, or use ncatted in "modify" mode for those attributes.

Answer (score 1):

By default, NCO propagates the metadata from the first variable on the RHS to the LHS so `v4` gets the same attributes as `v1` in Adrian's example. You can change or augment those attributes in the same `ncap2` command using the at-sign `@` to name attributes, e.g.,

```
ncap2 -O -s 'v4=(v1*0.1)+(v2*0.2)+(v3*0.2);v4@long_name="Fourth variable";v4@units="meters"' in.nc out.nc
```

Comment: Good point, if you don't mind I'll update my answer to point to that info for clarification in fact.